# Excel Add In is not loaded. A runtime error occurred during the loading of the COM Add-In

Tags: .net, vsto, visual-studio-addins, excel-addins

My VSTO Excel addin suddenly stopped working.
The machine is Windows 8 x64 and i am using Excel 2010.
The addin is written in visual studio 2010

Here's what i tried

The Loadbehaviour in the registry is 2.
I changed it to 3 and load the addin, but still the addin is not loaded and LoadBehaviour is changed back to 2.

Added the VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS environment variable and set it to 0.
Added the VSTO_LOGALERTS environment variable and set ti to 1.

I restarted my excel and still addin is not loaded and i didn't get any error pop displaying the error message.

I cannot find any log file and my search for *.manifest.log resulted no results.

I am struck here and my addin is listed in inactive application addins and i can't find error why it is not active.

Please bring me out of this.

Comment: Is addin listed in COM addins?

Comment: Yes my addin is listed in COM addins

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a chance to check out the Disabled Items list in Excel?

Microsoft Office applications can disable add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when an add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the Startup event handler in your add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when an add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable an add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the add-in again.

You can read more about that in the [How to: Re-enable an Add-in That Has Been Disabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268871.aspx) article.

Comment: As my application is listed in inactive application addins, i presume that my application is soft disabled. I tried to enable it by following the steps in the link but my addin is not enabled. Where can i find the error that is stopping my addin from loading up?

Comment: Try creating a new empty add-in project. Does it work? Also I'd suggest checking the Trust Center settings. Are VBA macro settings applied to add-ins?

Comment: Error is occurring in the customer machine i am deploying. I can't create empty addin project there. The addin is getting installed and loaded in other machines and also in my dev machine. I checked the trust center settings for excel and all macros are enabled in macro settings and addins settings are fine i.e "require application addins to be signed by trusted publisher" is not  checked. Am i missing anything?

Comment: I'd suggest testing a clean add-in project to make sure that the issue doesn't come from your code. Make sure that you deployed all the required prerequsites for the add-in.